# iOS - local notification not updating badge number

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am trying to update the local notification badge count, but it always showing 1. Badge count is not consistent. I am using the following code:

```
 NSCalendar *gregCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [gregCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear  | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSDateFormatter *outputFormatterHour = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [outputFormatterHour setDateFormat:@"HH"];
    NSDateFormatter *outputFormatterMin = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [outputFormatterMin setDateFormat:@"mm"];
    int hour = [[outputFormatterHour stringFromDate:_selectTimePicker.date] intValue];
    int min = [[outputFormatterMin stringFromDate:_selectTimePicker.date] intValue];

    [dateComponent setHour:hour];
    [dateComponent setMinute:min];

    NSDate *fireDate = [gregCalendar dateFromComponents:dateComponent];

    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    [localNotification setAlertTitle:@"Title"];
    [localNotification setAlertBody:@"Body" ];
    [localNotification setAlertAction:@"Open App"];
    [localNotification setHasAction:YES];

    [localNotification setAlertLaunchImage:@"AppIcon"];


    [localNotification setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1];

    //localNotification.soundName = @"beep.wav";
    [localNotification setFireDate:fireDate];
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
    [localNotification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Comment: Instead of assuming that the current count is >1, set the count to some arbitrary number (say 42).  If the badge is set correctly, you know your assumption is invalid.

Comment: Log the count of `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]` and you will know what is wrong.

Comment: It is not updating the badge count when app is in background.